# Working with mkfifo and transport streams, is this possible?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, stream, named-pipes, transport

I want to execute a bash script that would do the following:

Application 'ffmpeg' generates a LIVE transport stream (.ts) file. I need to work on this live streaam (perform de-multiplexing, etc).

Now I know this has to be done via FIFOs; but here is my task.

I need to redirect the output of ffmpeg to write to a fifo, and then another application will work on that fifo contents. This happens continuously in real time until I press, say Ctrl+C.

Is this possible? 
Will I have to do this is two terminals?

I'm basically writing a bash script for the above operations (and more) so do I have to invoke two terminals, or maybe fork?

Kindly advise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What not just use a pipe?

Comment: ffmpeg doesn't support pipes; at least not named pipes. Plus I have to run three instances of ffmpeg simultaneously to three different pipes and then use the three pipes as input to a fourth ffmpeg instance that sort of combines them together.

Comment: Ffmpeg absolutely supports pipes.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg does support pipes.
Everything you have to done is approach as follows:

1. make a fifo

   ```
   mkfifo first.ts
   ```
2. run ffmpeg with pipe

   ```
   ffmpeg -i sample.ts -c copy -muxrate 5000000 pipe:1 > first.ts
   ```
3. run any other tools which work with transport stream files, e.g. OpenCaster tool tscbrmuxer which can add e.g. NIT table to transport stream file

   ```
   tscbrmuxer b:3008 NIT.ts b:5000000 first.ts > second.ts
   ```
4. If you want to stop 2 tools simply kill the last one that uses pipe/fifo. in out case you have to kill tscbrmuxer.

   ```
   kill tscbrmuxer
   ```

   OR
   If you are not running last tool in the background simply kill it with [ctrl+c]

Thanks to using such an approach (e.g. as a shell script or Python one) all tools that uses pipe/fifo will be terminated due to broken pipe.

I hope this will help you.