# ffmpeg working with named pipes - Ubuntu 18

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, pipe, ubuntu-18.04, named-pipes

I am trying to work ffmpeg with name pipes but I can't get it to work as I want. My idea is simple: I have multiple segments of video and audio, I will use ffmpeg to use them as inputs and produce one file which contains both audio and video. The result of this will be sent to a name pipe and then I will ffmpeg again to read from the name pipe and finally send the output as hls stream.

Heres what I tried so far

```
mkfifo stream
```

Loop through files

```
ffmpeg -i video01.mp4 -i audio01.mp3 -c copy pipe:1 > stream
```

This command will be inside python code to read the next video02.mp4 and audio02.mp3 and send output to stream.

Now ffmpeg has to read data from stream. Heres the command I tried

```
ffmpeg -i stream -c copy -hls_time 6 -hls_flags delete_segments stream.m3u8
```

When I try running first ffmpeg command it doesn't seem to "write data" into my pipe named stream. So when I try second ffmpeg it doesn't have anything to read and it justs hangs. What I noticed thought, is that if I run both commands using | it will output my stream.m3u8 but the problem is that I want to continuosly send data to my named pipe stream and another instance of ffmpeg to read from said named pipe  continuosly.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried this answers so far
[Working with mkfifo and transport streams, is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499804/working-with-mkfifo-and-transport-streams-is-this-possible)
[How to make ffmpeg write its output to a named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584220/how-to-make-ffmpeg-write-its-output-to-a-named-pipe)
https://superuser.com/questions/901339/continuous-streaming-from-an-empty-pipe-then-adding-data-to-the-pipe-on-demand

At first glance it seemed something really simple to do but I am missing something here and I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running both `ffmpeg`s at the same time? If you try to run just one at a time, it won't work.

Comment: Hi, Joseph. My idea is to run first instance to constantly send data to my named pipe. Second instance of ffmpeg will run in the background and listen to my named pipe and output hls stream.

What do you mean by "running one at a time won't work"?

Comment: A named pipe has a very tiny buffer. Once it fills up, any processes that try to write to it will hang until something else comes along to read from it. It sounds like you're running just the reader, seeing it's not working (because the buffer is empty), then killing it and running just the writer, and also seeing it's not working (because it filled up the buffer very quickly).

Comment: So, I just need to keep sending data to my named pipe and then make another instance of ffmpeg start listening to that pipe? Because it seems at the time I tried to read the pipe, the data was already gone.

Is that the right approach?

Comment: In a shell, if you do `cmd1 | cmd2`, then output goes from `cmd1` to `cmd2` and both run at the same time. But doing `cmd1 |` or `| cmd2` is complete nonsense. If you don't run both processes for your named pipe at the same time, it's similarly complete nonsense.

Comment: I understand your explation but thats not what I was trying to do or at least that's what I wanted to make clear.

Heres what I am going to try

ffmpeg -i video01.mp4 -i audio01.mp3 -c copy pipe:1 > stream

But at the same I will have a second instance of ffmpeg listening to "stream" and once it catches data it starts outputing my hls stream.

If it works I will let you know.